# Как подключить Redis cloud на heroku?

Tags: heroku, развертывание, redis, ruby-on-rails

Не пойму, как подключить redis на heroku.
Добавил аддон redis cloud к приложению, прописал в redis.rb следующее:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
else
  $redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
end
```

Кроме этого, еще надо что-то прописать? `REDISCLOUD_URL` где-то явно указать?
В консоле при попытке взаимодействовать с БД выводит:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас неверная конструкция if.

Для Rails 4:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    $redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
end
```

Не надо писать then, если условие не в одну строку. И вместо elsif - else.

[Инструкция здесь](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud).

Это для Resque и Redis.

```
# ../config/unicorn.rb

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # ...

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # ...

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```

Comment: Да, действительно if/else было неправильно записано, переписал этот фрагмент, но ошибка осталась.

P.S. Этот гайд от heroku уже несколько раз перечитал, перед тем как задать вопрос.

P.P.S. Есть реакция на функции, написанные неправильно, например, `$redis.set('234')` тут говорит, что не хватает одного аргумента, если же написать функцию правильно, то та же ошибка:

>Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: Он у вас по прежнему просится на локалхост. Проверьте heroku config. Там есть url RedisCloud?

Comment: В настройках REDISCLOUD_URL указан, я использую(впервые) unicorn, а там оказывается внешние зависимости надо оборачивать в before_fork и after_fork? не знаете как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Конфиг должен выглядеть так. С одним условием. Если вы хотите использовать именно Resque.
Вы как хотели Redis задействовать? В связке с чем-то или отдельно?

Comment: Отдельно, чисто один redis (+rails).

Comment: Тогда в конфиг Unicorn ничего не надо писать про Redis.
Достаточно настроить config/initializers/redis.rb
Проверь, есть ли REDISCLOUD_URL в heroku config

Comment: Заработал со строкой
 
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
    $redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)